# Ударение в слове "философский" в смысле "принадлежащий философу"

Tags: орфоэпия, словосочетания

Обычно в слове "*философский*" ударение ставится на третий слог, но будет ли это так, если я имею дело со значением "принадлежащий философу"? Не логичнее ли было бы сказать тогда "фил**О**софский"?
То есть речь не идет о философии как таковой, и не о философах в целом, и даже не о каких-либо свойствах некоторого философа, относящихся непосредственно к философии. Речь идет о простом отношении принадлежности, то есть, например, существует объект - вообще любой - которым обладает философ, и при этом сам объект никак к философии не относится.
Если говорить о вопросе подробнее, то я имею в виду английское словосочетание "*philosopher's stone*". То есть фактически - камень философа, но переведено оно обычно как "философский камень", где слово "философский" очевидно указывает не на свойства камня (в таком случае было бы "philosophical"), а на то, что этот камень принадлежит или принадлежал какому-то философу. Так что заменяя "камень" на любое другое понятие - например, на "нос", "жена", "юность" - и оставляя ударение на третьем слоге, мы получим уже менее осмысленные словосочетания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> не о философах в целом

В латинском оригинале - как раз о "**множественных**" философах, (lapis) *philosophorum*, буквально "**камень философов**". Русская терминология по пути буквализации не пошла (возможно, такое словосочетание ассоциировалось с "кораблем дураков", или была иная причина). Можно ли образовать притяжательное прилагательное с однозначным отнесением ко многим "философам" (в ед. числе было бы возможно "философов камень" - по аналогии с "сизифов")? Да и всегда ли "философский" (философический) относили к науке под названием "философия" а не к ранним философам как мудрецам? Первоначально это был "**философический камень**" (так было еще в конце 19 века).

> *...коагулировать въ настоящій **философический*** *камень..* Собрание разных
> достовѣрных химических книг... Johan Isaac Hollandus, 1787

Современные словари считают "философический" просто старой формой слова "философский". Так или иначе, содержание термина (символическое вещество, к которому стремилась алхимия) оказалось связано не с буквальной *принадлежностью философам*, а с их целью и общим делом, "философией" как старым символом просвещенности.

Comment: Да, история перевода пролила свет на многое, но я все еще не вижу причин соглашаться с устоявшейся версией. Вариант "философ камень", по-моему, гораздо более точный.

Comment: Замечание о том, что камень - "цель и общее дело" философов, а не их собственность как таковая, в самом деле справедливо, но в моем понимании оба варианта полностью вписываются в отношение принадлежности, как бы "**производности от**", тем более что и в латыни, и в английском на это есть строгое указание. А перевод "философический", по-моему, неверный в принципе, потому что ни к каким философам он вообще не отсылает, лишь к философии - вне зависимости от интерпретации слова.

Comment: Там я имею в виду "философов камень", конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Мысль интересная, но нет.
В БТС Кузнецова слово филос**о**фский имеет среди прочих и то самое значение "принадлежащий философу". Правда, использовать предлагается в переносном значении и как разговорное, но тем не менее.

> 4. Разг. Свойственный философу (2-3 зн.). *Относиться ко всему с философским*
>    *спокойствием. Быть в философском настроении*.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9

Так что мудрить не надо, ударение и в этом случае падает на третий слог.

Comment: Да, я видел это значение, но оно меня не удовлетворило. В вопросе я специально указал: "не о каких-либо свойствах некоторого философа, относящихся непосредственно к философии". То есть здесь в 4 пункте подразумевается, что у философа - как у человека занимающегося философией - сложился ряд качеств, которые можно в более серьезной или менее серьезной форме, напрямую или косвенно (например, через поверхностную ассоциацию) перенести на другие понятия. Но то значение слово "философский", которое я предложил, не имеет с этим ничего общего, оно подразумевает фактическую принадлежность философу.

Comment: То есть хотя мы и  можем сказать, например, "купеческая дочь" - "филос**о**фская дочь" мы не скажем.

Comment: *Да, я видел это значение, но оно меня не удовлетворило.* - ну это к Кузнецову тогда. Я не вижу причин сомневаться в сути им сказанного.

Comment: *о есть хотя мы и можем сказать, например, "купеческая дочь" - "философская дочь" мы не скажем.* - если речь идет о философе во 2-3 значении, то имеем право.  Для первого значения просто нет подходящего прилагательного. Это не повод изобретать новое ударение.

Comment: "Не удовлетворило" не в том смысле, что я сомневаюсь в каком-то из значений Кузнецова или не согласен с ними. "Не удовлетворило" в том смысле, что значения слова "философский", о котором говорю я, среди этих четырех значений вообще нет.

Comment: Меня не удовлетворило ваше объяснение. Во всех смыслах. ))) Могу только повторить, что это не повод изобретать новое ударение. Простите, это тупик.  тему в таком ключе больше не обсуждаю.

Comment: Просто вы в ответе говорите о _том самом значении "принадлежащий философу"_, и я вам пояснил, что **принадлежать философу** в смысле _"иметь родство с некоторыми атрибутами вообще любого философа (такими, которые и делают философа философом)"_ и **принадлежать философу** в смысле _"являться непосредственной собственностью какого-то конкретного философа"_ - это разные, в моем видении, вещи, и второго варианта в перечне значений у Кузнецова нет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117698/discussion-between-behemothus-and-rainermaria).

Answer (score 0):

Для носителей нашего языка ударение на соединительной гласной непривычно https://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=57509.0
И зачем нам мудрить с ударением, если изменив порядок слов (что в нашем языке вполне допустимо) получаем и однозначное, и более краткое - «камень философа».

Comment: Оно, конечно, так но слово философ в русском **не рассматривается** как составное, поэтому О - не является соединительной гласной. По вашей ссылке, простите, бред известного тролля, г-на Навескина. Не обсуждается.